# How do I update only the column, and leave the create_at, and updated_at as is?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table in mysql, I used Laravel.

I need to loop through all the rows in the logs table and set `babyId` to `1`

I tried this

## 1

```
$logs = BabyLog::all();


foreach ($logs as $log) {


    $log->babyId = 1; 
    $log->save();


}
```

---

## 2

```
$logs = BabyLog::all();


foreach ($logs as $log) {


    $log->babyId = 1; 
    $log->created_at = $log->created_at; 
    $log->updated_at = $log->updated_at; 
    $log->save();


}
```

It messed up my updated time. It set all the updated time of all my logs to right now. ;(

I didn't want that.

How do I update only the column, and leave the create_at, and updated_at as is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that.

```php
$log->timestamps = false;
$log->babyId = 1; 
$log->save();
```